# Generate file and download it from OpenERP

Tags: python, json, odoo

I have a python method in OpenERP that generate a json file. I would like to know how can I set the default path of the json will be local path, not a path on the server.

a part of my code have this with

```
open('/home/user/test.json', 'w')
```

as jsonfile, which saves the file on the server. I want the file to be saved on the client side location.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?
Please share me!

Thanks.

Comment: then you have to use binary field to store data and retrieve it via openerp (web service )

Comment: There is a good answer for you, please check this [link][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819207/download-file-locally-in-python